# Spring Validator Not Providing Message to Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently developing a Spring RESTful service and am using the validation annotation to ensure parameters within the object of the body of the request are present. However, for some reason the Spring validation does not appear to, by default, provide the client user with ANY information on why their request could have been invalid

Data Object class:

```
....
    @Min(10000000000L)
    @Max(19999999999L)
    private long id;
    
    private boolean restricted;
.....
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/userRestriction")
    public ResponseEntity<String> userRestriction(
            @Valid @RequestBody(required = true) User user) {
```

Post:

```
{
    "id":"A",
    "restricted":false
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-23T14:20:57.273+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/userRestriction"
}
```

Logs:

```
2020-07-23 09:20:57.271  WARN 28035 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `long` from String "A": not a valid Long value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `long` from String "A": not a valid Long value
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 11] (through reference chain: myPackage.dataObjects.User["id"])]
```

I was hoping that Spring would be able to at least provide the exception in the error message to get me by through a Minimum Viable Product iteration, so that way while it may be obtuse, a client can still ultimately understand what they did wrong, and I could add custom error handling later, but this doesn't seem to be the case?

If not, what are the methods I'd need to implement in a error/exception handler class to correctly handle validator errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following class `BindingResult bindingResult` in the parameters of `userRestriction()`

```
@PostMapping("/userRestriction")
public ResponseEntity<String> userRestriction(
        @Valid @RequestBody(required = true) User user, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

Then inside your method you can do something like

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    //Whatever you want to do
}
```

`BindingResult` provides acces and handling to the validation of your Bean associated with `@Valid`

More information about how to handle it can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html

I would suggest you use the method `getAllErrors()` which will return a list of all the errors given by the validation.
You can also implement a custom exception to be thrown when these errors exist.

Let me give you a code snippet for implementing a handler exception with Spring

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
 extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(value 
  = { IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class })
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(
  RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
    String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, 
      new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
}
}
```

This is the most useful I have used so far, you just need to adapt it to your needs. You can find further information following this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: Thanks for that! So how would I go about all the possible errors that the default handler was taking care of? Looking at the tutorial and another one from baeldung (https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api) it looks like you use:
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAll(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {

However, when I try to put even a printline in that method, it doesn't get called when, say, I don't provide a body in the request. Is there another type of handler I need to extend?

Comment: Try to add this on the class you have created to be the exception handler `@RestControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)` instead of `@ControllerAdvice`

Comment: That doesn't appear to work either. When I remove the custom handler class, I get a body response when I send a post request without a body, but with the class (even with the above suggestion) as well as the baeldung suggested default exception handler method, all I get back is the HTTP 400 (BAD REQUEST) header, no body.

Comment: Figured it out! Turns out there are a lot of methods in ResponseEntityExceptionHandler that NEED to be overridden to return a complete response entity with error message. The default exception handler doesn't get called if Spring knows it can use one of the pre-defined methods. So for example, for the missing body issue not returning anything besides a 400 header, I needed to implement the handleHttpMessageNotReadable method, as the base one basically does nothing.

Comment: Yeah, true! I totally forgot about those methods. I am happy it worked.